How to Switch Power BI Dataset Based on Logged-in User Role (Microsoft Entra Security Group)?
In Power BI, I have a report where I need to mask data based on the logged-in user's role (determined by Microsoft Entra Security Group).
It appears that Power BI does not have a built-in feature to handle this directly.To address this, I'm considering maintaining two separate datasets: one with masked data and the other with unmasked data.
Is there a method to dynamically change the dataset source for the report based on the logged-in user?
Thank you,
Praveen

You don't need to change the source. You can use RLS to securely manage what is shown to different users.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric/security/service-admin-row-level-security

Thanks for the answer. I don't want to filter the Rows. It's mask/unmask the column data based on the user.

You could use OLS then. Have one column obfuscated and one clear text. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric/security/service-admin-object-level-security?tabs=table

And combine the OLS with Field Parameters to switch the column on the report automatically: https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2022/05/22/stopping-some-users-seeing-certain-columns-or-measures-in-your-power-bi-report-with-object-level-security-and-field-parameters/
